# Prevent people from posting to the wall of a Facebook business page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Is there a way to stop people posting on the wall of a business page?

I’ve found [this guide](https://en-gb.facebook.com/help/115469971891543), but it seems to only be for personal accounts, rather than business accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These steps are in the guide:

To choose whether other people can post on your Page's Timeline:

1. Click Settings at the top of your Page.
2. Click Posting Ability.
3. Click to choose Disable posts by other people on my Page Timeline.
4. Click Save Changes.

You can also choose "Allow other people to post to my Page Timeline", if you do so you can choose whether to:

- Allow photo and video posts.
- Review posts by other people before they're shown on your Page.

Answer (score 1):

I have just got some helpful information related your question. You can do following :

You have 2 options to limit access to your page, you can remove someone or ban someone. When you remove someone from your Page, they will no longer like it. This is a good option for people you don't want following your Page's posts in their news feeds.

When you ban someone from your Page, they will still like it but will no longer be able to post to your Page, comment on posts or share content from your Page to other places on Facebook. We recommend banning people who continually post spam on your Page.

> For more information on protecting your Page, please visit our Help
>   Center:
>
> https://www.facebook.com/help/329858980428740/?ref=u2u

Answer (score 0):

If it's a business page, go to "Settings" that is in a column on the left side of the page. Click "Page Settings" then "Visitor Posts." Click "Disable posts by other members" and save. You don't have to block or ban anyone to limit the content on your page. Good luck.